# Trouble adding a DNS subdomain using Bind9.9, with the NS in the subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, subdomain

I had a setup using an older Bind which is no longer working once I started using Bind9.9... The named.conf is still the same, with recursion active and the zone I'm using has no forwarders. However, I get the error that there is no glue record for the NS, although it is there... is this something that the new Bind won't allow; ie, having the NS in the subdomain itself?

In the old Bind I was using Red Hat, now using CentOS7.

Here is the zone file:

```
$TTL 86400

rd2t9g9.redes.intranet. IN SOA  pc9-1-v1-9 root (

                                        42      ; serial
                                        3H      ; refresh
                                        15M     ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        1D )    ; minimum
                        IN NS pc9-1-v1-9

pc9-1-v1-9              IN A 192.168.99.11

pc9-1-v2-9              IN A 192.168.99.12

area1                   IN NS pc9-2-v2-9.area1

area1                   IN NS duplicate

duplicate               IN A 192.168.99.23

pc9-2-v2-9.area1        IN A 192.168.99.22
```

When running checkzone, I get the message

```
zone rd2t9g9.redes.intranet/IN: area1.rd2t9g9.redes.intranet/NS 'pc9-2-v2-9.area1.rd2t9g9.redes.intranet' (out of zone) has no addresses records (A or AAAA)
zone rd2t9g9.redes.intranet/IN: loaded serial 42
OK
```

The file is exactly the same as when running the old Bind; it will work if the NS is in the domain (ie duplicate), but won't allow me to have a NS in the subdomain (but it used to!)

Any ideas?

Will also add the named.conf file:

```
options {

    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };

    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };

    directory   "/var/named";

    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";

    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";

    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";

    allow-query     { localhost; };

    recursion yes;

    dnssec-enable no;
    dnssec-validation no;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {

    type hint;

    file "named.ca";

};

zone "rd2t9g9.redes.intranet" IN {

    type master;

    file "zone_A";

    allow-update { none; };

    forwarders { };
};

zone "99.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {

    type master;

    file "rev_zone";

    allow-update { none; };

};


include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";

include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

Comment: I agree, this is very unusual. Everything appears to be correct here. Do you see any inline control codes if you use `cat -e` to display the contents of this file? There might be an invisible character adjacent to `pc9-2-v2-9.area1`, which would change how BIND interprets it.

Comment: It would be interesting to have an ideia of the *previous* version of BIND in use, to check the release notes of the intermediate versions. I would definitively create the area1 as a true subdomain instead of trying to fake it. Which version of RH was it before?

Comment: Thanks - there are no inline control codes. Previous used Red Hat 6 (about 10 years old)

Comment: Based on the delegation information that you have, `192.168.99.23` and `192.168.99.22` should have the `area1.rd2t9g9.redes.intranet` zone. What result does `dig @192.168.99.23 pc9-2-v2-9.area1.rd2t9g9.redes.intranet +norec` and `dig @192.168.99.22 pc9-2-v2-9.area1.rd2t9g9.redes.intranet +norec` produce?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing has changed in terms of what is allowed in that regard. Possibly `named-checkzone` has more validation, depending on which older version you are comparing it to, or the environment where you run this is set up differently.

As the name that this `NS` record points to is not inside the zone that you are validating, `named-checkzone` is looking up the name in DNS (using the system's configured resolver server).

Does `pc9-2-v2-9.area1.rd2t9g9.redes.intranet` have an address record if you try looking it up on the same host where you run `named-checkzone`?

Ie, does `dig pc9-2-v2-9.area1.rd2t9g9.redes.intranet A` and/or `dig pc9-2-v2-9.area1.rd2t9g9.redes.intranet AAAA` yield a positive answer?
If not, the warning message is expected.

If you, for whatever reason, do not want `named-checkzone` to do this type of validation (you probably do, it is a real problem if these address records are missing on the authoritative end), there is the [`-i` option](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/man.named-checkzone.html) which can be used to specify a different validation mode (eg `-i local`).

Comment: With the current config, I cannot get the A record for pc9-2-v2-9.area1.rd2t9g9.redes.intranet. I don't know why Bind doesn't "see" that the info is there! The child server is up and running, but the upper zone just isn't delegating!

Comment: Btw, just added the named.conf file... thanks guys!

Comment: @JoãoCarlosMarquesSilva Which resolver server is used (`resolv.conf`)? If your local `named` instance is not the server used, it would be impossible for anything else to query it (it only listens on loopback).

Comment: its the local named server... It must be something in the Bind configuration, I guess

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use area1.rd2t9g9.redes.intranet elements inside rd2t9g9.redes.intranet.

This leads to `named-checkzone` complaining there are elements out of zone, because the server to which the subdomain areas1.rd2t9g9.redes.intranet probably does not exist yet, and as such `named-checkzone` cannot resolve the names. The warning will go away once the subdomains are properly configured.

The configuration as you have it is supposed to work- however as later BIND versions are know to be more strict, I cannot vouch for it. One way of not having the warning would be to take out the ".area1" and configure this way for your purposes.

```
$TTL 86400
@                       IN SOA  pc9-1-v1-9 root.localhost. (
                                    42      ; serial
                                    3H      ; refresh
                                    15M     ; retry
                                    1W      ; expire
                                    1D )    ; minimum

                        IN NS pc9-1-v1-9

pc9-1-v1-9              IN A 192.168.99.11
pc9-1-v2-9              IN A 192.168.99.12
area1                   IN NS pc9-2-v2-9
area1                   IN NS duplicate
duplicate               IN A 192.168.99.23
pc9-2-v2-9              IN A 192.168.99.22
```

I also do prefer the @ abbreviation instead of writing down the zone yet again, as it cuts in mistakes when dealing with several zones.

I also changed the root in SOA from root to root.localhost as the RFC specifies it is an email with a "." going for "@". You may use your own email instead of root@localhost.

Mind you that BIND 9.9 has several new changes, and one that will probably make difference in labs is that the new slave files are now in raw/binary format for performance reasons. If need be for educational purposes, BIND 9.9 can be configured to keep them in text format.

Comment: Regarding the `SOA` `RNAME` value, your change makes for an address `root@localhost.rd2t9g9.redes.intranet`.

Comment: ok Rui, will get back to you on the slave file; currently am using the raw format in the slave file :). The main problem persists, though. Ofcourse I could put the NS server in the upper zone and problem solved, but also for educational purposes, wanted to put it in the child zone